# Formtastic Creating a form without users

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, semantics, formtastic

I'm creating a web application with formtastic. I installed the gem and wrote my code like this:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @index do |form| %>
<%= form.inputs do %>
<%= form.input :name %>
<%= form.input :born_on, :start_year => 1997 %>
<%= form.input :description, :as => :text %>
<%= form.input :female, :as => :radio, :label => "Gender", :collection => [["Male", false], ["Female", true]] %>
<% end %>
<%= form.actions do %>
<%= form.action :submit, :as => :button %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

I want the form to appear on the index page which is why I have @index. For some reason I can't do @index. How would I reference the top line so that it renders a form on the index page? Currently my index page has nothing in it, but it is defined in the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

form_for helper expects some object that responds to fields You refer inside Your form. Here is an example of using semantic_form_for with plain Ruby object: http://affy.blogspot.com/2010/02/using-formtasic-without-activerecord.html.

Also the object You specify for form doesn't effect *which* page is being rendered. Are You sure You are not mixing up something? Maybe if You share a bit more of Your controller code we might help You better.

Comment: oohhhh ok. So I would need to create an object inside my controller and for each object that I create I can use semantic_form_for @"the desired object which needs a form rendered", right? I guess I was just confused about the rendering of the page. Thank you for the help, the link you provided clarifies your point well!

Comment: If You need a plain form, you can use Rails form_tag helper, check [API doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag
)
Formtastic and simple_form mainly exist to provide form helpers for ActiveRecord objects( error messages returned by validations, fields adjust to types specified in objects columns). Check Railscasts for more info:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/184-formtastic-part-1
http://railscasts.com/episodes/185-formtastic-part-2
http://railscasts.com/episodes/234-simple-form
http://railscasts.com/episodes/234-simple-form-revised (paid)